# wget recursive folder structure with multiple index.html files in tree

Tags: linux, command-line, wget

By default wget -r downloads directories as directoryname.html. I'd like it to download to directoryname/index.html

So instead of:

```
index.html
contact.html
support.html
```

I'd like:

```
index.html
contact/index.html
support/index.html
```

Is this posible with wget?

Comment: Yep. I get the site downloading correctly just not in the correct file format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I want to mirror a web site I use:

```
$ wget -m -E -nH -np --cut-dirs=2 http://site/a/b/
```

This way everything under the directory "b" will be downloaded.  If your target directory is at a different level, you need to adjust --cut-dirs accordingly.

Comment: This is useful but I want every directory to be downloaded this way. Perhaps I need a shell script?

Comment: What do you mean by you want every directory to be downloaded?  The command should recursively download for all directories in and under site/a/b.

Comment: It created foldername.html for child subdirectories. I need foldername/index.html for child subdirectories

Comment: @Ben What is the final solution to this? This answer command doesn't actually solves it....

Comment: I am not ben but get notified since I answered this... How is this command not working for you? The command should work, only that you have to be careful how to specify `--cut-dirs` if you are using the option.